# In trino I keep getting `Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables`

Tags: users, access-control, trino

I just created a new user `dataengineer` and user group `data-engineer`

When I try to connect with the user `dataengineer` using dbeaver I get the following errors.

```
SQL Error [4]: Query failed (#20210927_124120_00084_kcmzr): Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
Query failed (#20210927_124120_00084_kcmzr): Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
Query failed (#20210927_124120_00084_kcmzr): Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
    io.trino.spi.security.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
    Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
```

When I try to connect using the same user from the trino cli I get the following errors

```
trino:jdbc> select 1;
_col0
-------
    1
(1 row)

Query 20210927_143506_00011_m9sds, FINISHED, 1 node
https://trino.afsouth1ctcld.net/ui/query.html?20210927_143506_00011_m9sds
Splits: 1 total, 1 done (100,00%)
CPU Time: 0,0s total,     0 rows/s,     0B/s, 0% active
Per Node: 0,0 parallelism,     0 rows/s,     0B/s
Parallelism: 0,0
Peak Memory: 0B
0,34 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

trino:jdbc> select * from system.jdbc.tables limit 10;
Query 20210927_144444_00018_m9sds failed: Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
io.trino.spi.security.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied: Cannot select from table system.jdbc.tables
```

So the user can connect to trino but not query the system tables.
If I connect with a different user called data science it works without any issues.

This is what my group.txt and rules.json file looks like

```
group.txt: |-
data-science:datascience
data-engineer:dataengineer

rules.json: |-
{
  "catalogs": [
    {
      "user": "dpadmin",
      "allow": "all"
    },
    {
      "group": "data-engineering|data-platform-admin",
      "catalog": ".*",
      "allow": "all"
    },
    {
      "group": "data-science",
      "catalog": "(iceberg)",
      "allow": "all"
    },
    {
      "group": "data-science",
      "catalog": ".*",
      "allow": "read-only"
    },
    {
    "catalog": "system",
    "allow": "none"
    }
  ],
  "schemas": [
    {
      "user": "dpadmin",
      "schema": ".*",
      "owner": true
    },
    {
      "group": "data-engineering",
      "schema": ".*",
      "owner": true
    },

    {
      "group": "data-science",
      "catalog": ".*",
      "schema": ".*",
      "owner": false
    },
    {
      "user": "guest",
      "owner": false
    }
  ],
  "tables": [
    {
      "group": "data-science",
      "privileges": ["SELECT", "INSERT", "DELETE", "OWNERSHIP"],
      "catalog": "(iceberg)",
      "schema": "(ds_scratch)"
    },
    {
      "group": "data-science",
      "privileges": ["SELECT"],
      "catalog": ".*",
      "schema": ".*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is related to a problem with how the trino authorization system works.

Take from the [git issue](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/2987#issuecomment-612201933)

> You will need to create policies at the Catalog level, Schema level and Table level in order to ensure access.
>
> Access determination does not drill down to lower levels. The default policy is deny and as such, the first check will indeed end up
> with access denied.

So because I didn't have table-level permissions defined for the data-engineer group it was defaulting to deny

I fixed this by adding the following to the tables rules.

```
  "tables": [
    {
      "group": "data-engineering|data-platform-admin",
      "privileges": ["SELECT", "INSERT", "DELETE", "OWNERSHIP", "GRANT_SELECT"],
      "catalog": ".*",
      "schema": ".*"
    },
```

I put this ahead of the data-science rules as the rules are evaluated in order and I want users in the data-engineering group to get more access then those in the data-science group. But the same users might be defined in both groups via complex LDAP user queries and group matching. I tested and this works as I expect it to work.

Comment: Essentially you have to define permissions for each user at all three levels, catalogues, schemas and tables. 
It defaults to deny. so any place you don't specify permissions for a user will come up as a deny.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I am facing a similar issue but I am doing this at catalog level and wanted to know how can I grant an access to the user for a single table and avoid this error ? Is is possible to create system catalog access file ?